# Attribute Error in python, object has no attribute

Tags: python-3.x, class, object, inheritance, attributes

I am new to inheritance in classes and for some reason, the attributes in this code don't seem to be sharing correctly.  I'm not sure what the issue is.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age, occupation):
      self.name = name
      self.age = age
      self.occupation = occupation
  
    def say_hello(self):
      print(f"Hello, my name is {self.name}.")
  
    def say_age(self):
      print(f"I am {self.age} years old.")
    
class Superhero(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, age, occupation, secret_identity, nemesis):
      self.secret_identity = secret_identity
      self.nemesis = nemesis

hero = Superhero("Spider-Man", 17, "student", "Peter Parker", "Green Goblin")
print(hero.name())
```

Comment: `name` is not a function, it is an attribute. You need to use `hero.name`. Next time please be more clear about your exception, preferably copying it.

Comment: I didn't say that name was a function.  To be clearer, the error was AttributeError:  'Superhero' object has no attribute 'name'.  There is no mention of functions in my title or the post.

Comment: `hero.name()` means that you are calling a function called `name` inside `hero`. Hence why I said that `name` is not a function, it is an attribute, remove the parenthesis.

Comment: Oh!  I see what you mean now.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not calling the `super` constructor in your `Superhero` class.
You should do as follow:

```py
class Superhero(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, age, occupation, secret_identity, nemesis):
      super().__init__(name, age, occupation)
      self.secret_identity = secret_identity
      self.nemesis = nemesis
```

BTW: you didn't define a function named `name`. If you want to print the name you should remove the `()`, e.g `print(hero.name)`